# How to uninstall R that was self-compiled on OS X?

Tags: r

I installed a pre-compiled version of R-3.3.3 on my computer and also used `./configure` and `make` to install a R-3.2.3. I found out that my RStudio is using 3.3.3, and now I want to delete 3.2.3. How can I do it?

Comment: If you *manually* configured and installed it, my guess is that you have to *manually* delete it. There is nothing R-centric or even programming-centric about this question. (Did you try `make uninstall`?)

Comment: If you installed it in the proper Frameworks version numbered directory, then you should be able to just delete the whole version directory. You might first want to see if the packages in that directory should be copied to the `../lbrary/` directory of the newer version and updated properly with `checkBuilt=TRUE`.